# How to do Sub Menu with Mutiple Level in Android Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-navigation-graph

I don't have any idea for this request yet: Can anyone help me with an idea? I would be very grateful.
I have a request like this. On my android screen.  There can be many levels of menus. For example If there was only 1 menu level it would look like the first image. And when I click on the area I drew in red, it will display the content on the right side.
But if my menu has 2 levels it will look like the 2nd image.
On the contrary, if my menu has more than 2 levels, the next level will replace the previous level. it's like from 2nd image to 3rd image.

[image]

I have no ideal for now.